# lazy and lazy_eval from lazyeval package

Tags: r

If I write:

```
> lazy_1 <- lazy(x+y, env = globalenv())
> lazy_1
<lazy>
  expr: x + y
  env:  <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
> x <- 1 ; y <- 2
> lazy_eval(lazy_1)
[1] 3
```

This makes sense to me as globalenv() is the environment in which to evaluate the expression as states by ?lazy

But when I write:

```
> rm(list = ls())
> env_2 <- new.env()
> env_2$x <- 6
> env_2$y <- 3
> lazy_2 <- lazy(x+y, env = env_2)
> lazy_2
<lazy>
  expr: x + y
  env:  <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
> lazy_eval(lazy_2)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found
```

I would expect the same behavior from globalenv and env_2

Note that if I force the structure of lazy_2 as I assumed it should have been:

```
> lazy_2$env <- env_2
> lazy_eval(lazy_2)
[1] 9
```

everything works fine.

Possibly I miss understanding something very basic but any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Looks like a bug to me: the implementation of lazy doesn't seem to access `env` at all. This is for the current development version, consider filing an issue at https://github.com/hadley/lazyeval/issues. You can @-mention me there if you like.

Comment: Workaround `lazy_2 <- lazy_(quote(x+y), env = env_2)`